# Code after Task.Delay in delegate not executing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to concurrently process partitions of a list. For each integer in each partition of the list I am trying to wait for that amount of time.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public async static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting.");
        var values = Enumerable.Range(0,1000).ToList();

        await Task.WhenAll(
            from partition in Partitioner.Create(values).GetPartitions(10)
            select Task.Run(async delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("Entered");
                using (partition)
                    while (partition.MoveNext()){               
                        var delay = partition.Current;
                        await Task.Delay(delay);
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Waited {0} milliseconds",delay));

                    }
            }));
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

**Execution appears to stop after Task.Delay(delay):**

```
Starting.
Entered
Entered
Waited 0 milliseconds
Entered
Entered
Entered
Entered
Entered
Entered
Entered
Entered
```

Comment: If my collection has 1000 elements and I partition that into 10 segments, shouldn't partition.MoveNext() return True for 100 iterations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

Change your `Main` definition to return a `Task`:

```
public async static Task Main()
```

**Longer answer**

Asynchronous methods actually run synchronously at first, up until the first `await`. If the `Task` that is returned by whatever method you called (`Task.WhenAll` in this case) has not completed yet, then the `await` keyword makes things asynchronous by returning a `Task` to the calling method, and signing up the rest of the method as a continuation on that `Task`.

So that means that your `Main` method actually returns after the first `Task.Delay()` is hit, beacuse that returns a `Task`, which triggers `Task.Run` to return a `Task`, which triggers `Task.WhenAll()` to return a `Task`. Since your `Main` method returns `void`, then .NET has no idea anything is still running and your program ends.

If you return a `Task`, then .NET will wait until that `Task` is completed.

If you want, there is extra reading [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/) about the valid `Main` signatures.

Note that the `async` method signatures only work in C# 7.1+. If you can't use C# 7.1+, then you can remove `async` from the `Main` method and use [`Task.WaitAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall) instead of `await Task.WhenAll()` (but you also have to call `.ToArray()` on the collection, since `WaitAll()` doesn't have an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<Task>` like `WhenAll()` does). That will block the main thread, but it's not really a big deal in a console app.

Comment: Very good and pragmatic explanation!