# Not awaiting an async call is still async, right?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm sorry if this is a silly question (or a duplicate).

I have a function `A`:

```
public async Task<int> A(/* some parameters */)
{
    var result = await SomeOtherFuncAsync(/* some other parameters */);

    return (result);
}
```

the I have another function `B`, calling `A` but not using the return value:

```
public Task B(/* some parameters */)
{
    var taskA = A(/* parameters */); // #1

    return (taskA);
}
```

Note that `B` is not declared `async` and is not awaiting the call to `A`. The call to `A` is not a fire-and-forget call - `B` is called by `C` like so:

```
public async Task C()
{
    await B(/* parameters */);
}
```

Notice that at **#1**, there's no `await`. I have a coworker that claims that this makes the call to `A` synchronous and he keeps coming up with `Console.WriteLine` logs that seemingly prove his point.

I tried pointing out that just because we don't wait for the results inside `B`, the task chain *is* awaited and the nature of the code inside `A` doesn't change just because we don't await it. Since the return value from `A` is not needed, there's no need to await the task at the call site, as long as *someone up the chain awaits it* (which happens in `C`).

My coworker is very insistent and I began to doubt myself. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: I'd love to see the `Console.WriteLine` code that seemingly proves that this is synchronous.

Comment: "Insistent" is not the same thing as "demonstrably correct".  Your co-worker *may* have a point, or *may* be completely mistaken.  (Your contrived example may also be removing something else in the overall operation.)  Remove personalities from the equation and create a test to demonstrate what you expect the code to be doing.  A console app which immediately ends (doesn't read input) is particularly useful for this because if the async operation takes some time and isn't awaited then the application would terminate before whatever the side-effect is of that operation can be observed.

Comment: @David There was actually a great example of that in [a question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57894077/1202807), except it was because the `Main` method was `async void`, thus the framework had no idea any task was still running and terminated the program. It was running asynchronously, even though the framework wasn't awaiting it.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: Nice example.  I've seen some interesting "tests" my similarly insistent co-workers, and I'm bookmarking Eric Lippert's answer below for future reference the next time it happens.  One example on a previous project was a programmer who was sure that his "fire and forget" code (hiding something asynchronous behind a synchronous interface and never awaiting it) would always work, because it "worked" in his WinForms app.  Which was only a coincidence because the operation "worked" in the time it took him to close the app.  In a Console App the operation never completed.

Comment: @David Why do you call this example contrived? It exactly demonstrates the scenario in question (of course, the actual functions are different and they take actual parameters, etc.)

Comment: @xxbbcc: "Contrived: Deliberately created rather than arising naturally or spontaneously." - Is that not the case?  The method names imply as much at least.  And the thing about examples like this is that if there's a misunderstanding between you and your colleague about the actual code, creating a different example to show us only shows us what you think the understanding is.  It *may* be precisely on point, but it's not the actual code being discussed by you and your colleague so it *may* miss something. "Contrived" isn't an insult, just an indication that we're looking at a made up example.

Comment: @xxbbcc: My point is that you can show this entire exchange to your colleague (and if he won't listen to Eric Lippert of all people, reasonable discourse may be lost entirely), but you could also create a test to demonstrate to the colleague.  That test would also of course be "contrived", but that would be exactly what's called for.  The test would either demonstrate your point and correct his misgivings, or he would point out that the test is missing something in the original that he was failing to communicate and the conversation can broaden to include that point. Either way, collaboration.

Comment: @David Ah I get what you meant. The example is only contrived in the sense that I simplified function names, removed logging and logic that doesn't pertain to the problem. Otherwise it's the actual code that I discussed with my coworker.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I'm sorry if this is a silly question

It is not a silly question. It is an important question.

> I have a coworker that claims that this makes the call to A synchronous and he keeps coming up with Console.WriteLine logs that seemingly prove his point.

That is the fundamental problem right there, and you need to educate your coworker so that they stop misleading themselves and others. **There is no such thing as an asynchronous call**.  The *call* is not the thing that is asynchronous, **ever**. Say it with me. **Calls are not asynchronous in C#**. In C#, when you call a function, that function is **called immediately after all the arguments are computed**.

If your coworker or you believes that there is such a thing as an asynchronous call, you are in for a world of pain because your beliefs about how asynchrony works will be very disconnected from reality.

So, is your coworker correct? Of course they are. **The call to `A` is synchronous because all function calls are synchronous**.  But the fact that they believe that there is such a thing as an "asynchronous call" means that they are badly mistaken about how asynchrony works in C#.

If specifically your coworker believes that `await M()` somehow makes the call to `M()` "asynchronous", then your coworker has a big misunderstanding.  `await` is an *operator*. It's a complicated operator, to be sure, but it is an operator, and it operates on values.   `await M()` and `var t = M(); await t;` are *the same thing*.  The await happens *after* the call because the `await` *operates on the value that is returned*.  `await` is **NOT** an instruction to the compiler to "generate an asynchronous call to M()" or any such thing; there is no such thing as an "asynchronous call".

If that is the nature of their false belief, then you've got an opportunity to educate your coworker as to what `await` means.  `await` means something simple but powerful. It means:

- Look at the `Task` that I'm operating on.
- If the task is completed exceptionally, throw that exception
- If the task is completed normally, extract that value and use it
- If the task is incomplete, sign up the remainder of this method as the continuation of the awaited task, and return a *new* `Task` representing *this call's* incomplete asynchronous workflow to *my caller*.

That's all that `await` does. It just examines the contents of a task, and if the task is incomplete, it says "well, we can't make any progress on this workflow until that task is complete, so return to my caller who will find something else for this CPU to do".

> the nature of the code inside A doesn't change just because we don't await it.

That's correct.  We synchronously call `A`, and it returns a `Task`. The code after the call site does not run until `A` returns.  The interesting thing about `A` is that **`A` is allowed to return an incomplete `Task` to its caller**, and that task represents *a node in an asynchronous workflow*.  The workflow is *already* asynchronous, and as you note, it makes no difference to `A` what you do with its return value *after* it returns; `A` has no idea whether you are going to `await` the returned `Task` or not.  `A` just runs as long as it can, and then either it returns a completed-normally task, or a completed-exceptionally task, or it returns an incomplete task.  But nothing you do at the call site changes that.

> Since the return value from A is not needed, there's no need to await the task at the call site

Correct.

> there's no need to await the task at the call site, as long as someone up the chain awaits it (which happens in C).

Now you've lost me. Why does anyone *have* to await the `Task` returned by `A`?  **Say why you believe that someone is *required* to `await` that `Task`, because you might have a false belief.**

> My coworker is very insistent and I began to doubt myself. Is my understanding wrong?

Your coworker is almost certainly wrong. Your analysis seems correct right up to the bit where you say that there is a *requirement* that every `Task` be `await`ed, which is not true. It is *strange* to not `await` a `Task` because it means that you wrote a program where you started an operation and do not care about when or how it completes, and it certainly *smells bad* to write a program like that, but there is not a *requirement* to `await` every `Task`. If you believe that there is, again, say what that belief is and we'll sort it out.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: Not at all. Calls in C# are very straightforward. Control *leaves* the caller, *enters* the callee, and *remains* in the callee until the callee either *returns* or *throws*. Asynchronous methods are special because *they can return before their workflow is complete*. How does that work? *When they do so, they make a delegate that, when called, resumes the workflow from where it left off*, and that delegate is the *continuation* of the returned task. When the task completes, the continuation is invoked and the workflow resumes.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: But the fact that *asynchronous methods can return before their workflow is complete* does not change the fact that *control remains in the callee until it returns*.  How could it not? The thread only has *one* point of control; that's what a thread is!

Comment: Yeah, I get it :) I was just kidding. But in all seriousness, it certainly is an important point I see misunderstood constantly too. That sentence could be framed and put on the wall: "There is no such thing as an asynchronous call."

Comment: @EricLippert But there are not delegate continuations though, are there? The whole async function is compiled into a single function partitioned by the await points into a state machine and the state of the function is saved just before returning.

Comment: Right, there are some optimizations that can be made in practice. But it is conceptually more clear to envision the continuation as a delegate that magically picks up where the workflow left off.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm sorry, it's probably just mis-phrasing on my part - I don't believe that every call has to be awaited because of some rule; it's just typically not awaiting an async operation doesn't produce a reliable program. I was trying top impress upon my coworker that to get certainty that a task is finished (not a fire-and-forget task), it has to be awaited somewhere but that somewhere doesn't need to be the immediate call site that started the task.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm also sorry, I think loosely using the word "call" gave you the impression that I think function calls can be asynchronous - I do not, in fact, think so. I think I probably should've used "workflow" instead, as you did. I think you correctly assume that my coworker believes `await` makes the call asynchronous (I have several coworkers with similar beliefs). It was his insistence (which I thought was misplaced but couldn't think of a quick way to disprove it) with some console outputs that made me question my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I think in everyday discussion it's hard to consciously separate "call" and "workflow" - I think Eric's history with the compiler makes it easier for him to do so. I regularly talk about "asynchronous calls", even though I understand how statements are executed in a function one at a time. (I had to rewrite this comment 3 times for precision and I'm still not sure I wrote what I tried to say.)

Answer (score 6):

You are right. Creating a task does only that and it does not care when and who will await its result. Try putting `await Task.Delay(veryBigNumber);` in `SomeOtherFuncAsync` and the console output should be what you would expect.

This is called eliding and I suggest you read [this blogpost](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), where you can see why you should or should not do such thing.

Also some minimal (little convoluted) example copying your code proving you right:

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start of main {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            var task = First();
            Console.WriteLine($"Middle of main {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await task;
            Console.WriteLine($"End of main {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        static Task First()
        {
            return SecondAsync();
        }

        static async Task SecondAsync()
        {
            await ThirdAsync();
        }

        static async Task ThirdAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start of third {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"End of third {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
```

This writes `Middle of main` before `End of third`, proving that it is in fact asynchronous. Furhtermore you can (most likely) see that the ends of functions run on different thread than the rest of the program. Both beginnings and the middle of main will always run on the same thread because those are in fact synchrnous (main starts, calls the function chain, third returns (it may return at the line with the `await` keyword) and then main continues as if there was no asynchronous function ever involved. The endings after the `await` keywords in both functions may run on any thread in the ThreadPool (or in synchronization context you are using).

Now it is interesting to note, that if `Task.Delay` in `Third` did not take very long and actually finished synchronously, all of this would run on a single thread. What's more, even though it would run asynchronously, it **might** all run on a single thread. There is no rule stating that an async function will use more than one thread, it may very well just do some other work while waiting for some I/O task to finish.

Comment: You can print thread id at each step to follow execution flow `Console.WriteLine("StepX" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`

Comment: @Kalten I added it there, but it is important to note, that asynchronous does not mean parallel and the thread might be the same.