# Does Calling an async function( which is also calling an async function ) synchrously blocks UI in Win Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await

I had a Win Form with different controls for collecting info from user and a button on it. On button click I am doing different validation before saving and in the end calling an async function depending on some condition (Like this):

```
button_CLick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
 validations()  
 if(conditiontrue) Then                
    Result()   // Will this call block UI
 else    
    savinglogic()   
 end if   
}

Private Async Sub Result()
 Dim result = Await Show()    
 If result = String.Empty Or result Is Nothing Then    
        Return      
 ElseIf (Await PostAsync(txtData(0).Text, txtData(1).Text, result)) Then      
        LogChangesForAudit()   
 Else  
       Return   
 End If   
End Sub    

Private Async Function Show() as Threading.Tasks.Task(of String)       
    Dim response =  await CalltoWebAPIAsynchronouslyAndShowDataToUser()          
    return UserInputString       
End Function

Private Async Function PostAsync(txtData(0).Text, txtData(1).Text, result)) as Threading.Tasks.Task(of Boolean)              
 Dim flag as Boolean=false     
 if savingdatafetchedfromSHow() then    
    flag=true      
 End if        
  return flag          
 End Function
```

Comment: Google "async void considered harmful" for useful hits.

Comment: I want to know whether the blocking of UI would be there or not

Comment: We cannot answer this because we do not see the code of `CalltoWebAPIAsynchronouslyAndShowDataToUser` - BTW the **calling** of any method is **always** synchron - read https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035833/1744164

Comment: CalltoWebAPIAsynchronouslyAndShowData is basically a httpclient calling a web api and fetching data from there. Then that data is shown to user in a drop down and then user is ask to select one value and userinput string is basically the value selected by the user.

Comment: I would expect calling `Result` to block.  Recommend to change `Result` to an `Async Function` returning `Task`, make `button_Click` `async` (an event handler is the one place where `async void` or `Async Sub` is appropriate), and `await Result` instead of calling `Result` in `button_Click`.

Comment: Hi Craig. Thanks for replying but why would calling  Result block the UI. Result is already calling an async function named Show()  with await, so compiler ahould not block the UI.  Actually its not blocking but then one of my coworker siad that we should make button click async. What is the need when UI is not blocked on calling result?