# Why is my asynchronous method not returning the thread to the thread pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm experimenting with the async/await pattern and have created a simple ASP.NET API.

In Startup.cs, I've set the number of threads to just 2:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 2);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 2);
```

I have a controller that inserts 500,000 objects into an in-memory database. This controller also has a method to find an object by GUID:

```
private void InitialiseDatabase()
{
    _context.Items.Add(new Item {
        Id = Guid.Parse("4ffc6ac9-b2ce-4323-8dc2-5a763ed23f2e") });

    for (int i = 0; i < 500_000; i++)
    {
        _context.Items.Add(new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItemAsync(Guid id)
{
    var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id);

    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return item;
}
```

To test how async works, I send two Postman requests for non-existent items. Each of these takes around 20 seconds to complete. While these are running, I send a request for an existing item, which should take a fraction of a second.

It was my understanding that when the await keyword is hit, control is yielded to the calling code, and if this is at the controller level, then the thread is returned to the thread pool for re-use.

This does not appear to be the case, the third request is only processed once one of the long-running requests is done.

Perhaps I've misunderstood how async works in ASP.NET.

Comment: Try doing this with a real DB.  You're "in-memory" DB likely doesn't actual yield control by doing any actual IO.  Alternatively you could simulate the IO by using `await Task.Delay(1000);`.  And understand that control is no yielded at the first await, but rather somewhere down the call chain.  Here's a really good answer from Eric Lippert that explains that method calls are not asynchronous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035605/not-awaiting-an-async-call-is-still-async-right/58035833#58035833

Comment: You're right! If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also see [this example](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/5796697).